# FIREBASE - Realtime database records deleted and created after updating from play store

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working with realtime database, but every time I update the app at the play store, the records are deleted and then a couple of new records are created with values then I don't know where they come from. They are not deleted all at once, but gradually, seconds apart. I don't understand, I even change the name child container, to test if the problem is between devices with persistent data set to true, but still happening, and I'm the only device using this parent.

This is driving me crazy! Anyone can help me? Thanks.

```
    articleListener = object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            data = mutableListOf()

            for (article in dataSnapshot.children) {
                val articleData = article.getValue(Article::class.java)
                articleData?.id = article.key

                data.indexOfFirst { art -> art.id == article.key }.let {
                    //if ID exists then overrides else add
                    if (it != -1) {
                        articleData?.let { it1 -> data[it] = it1 }
                    } else
                        articleData?.let { it1 -> data.add(it1) }
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
            // Getting Post failed, log a message
            Log.w("TAG", "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException())
        }
    }

    firebaseDatabase = try {
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().apply { setPersistenceEnabled(true) }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.w("Warn", e.toString())
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    }

                // I changed the container from articles to release_articles
    databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.reference.child("release_articles")
    databaseReference.orderByChild("date/time").startAt(getTodayInMillis().toDouble())
        .addValueEventListener(articleListener)
```

Comment: There should be a delete command. Otherwise the data cannot be deleted. An entire node can be disappeared if the child data is deleted or null. Check for the null values.

Comment: I cannot explain what was happening, I implemented the login as anonymous and 9 users were created, I don't know how, and the problems began, now I removed anonymous and implemented google oauth and everything is back no normal. My app is for internal tester with only 2 testers... I really don't know what happened

Comment: @PasanBhanuGuruge I have one delete command, at long press at the recycler view item, a dialog appears with yes or no, and removes from db, but it must be triggered manually

Comment: I think because of firebase anonymous auth. But I don't have a way to prove it.